# How do I fix 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' in this code?

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

I've been getting these errors very frequently in linked lists, stacks and queues. It would be great if anyone would point out the mistake that I'm making again and again.

Here's the code that I've written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
}*front=NULL,*rear=NULL;
void enqueue(struct Node *front,struct Node *rear,int ele)
{
    struct Node *temp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* ptr=front;
    if (temp==NULL)
        printf("Overflow");
    else
    {
        if (front==NULL)
        {
    temp->data=ele;
    temp->next=NULL;
    front=temp;
    printf("%d",front->data);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Srishti");
        while(ptr->next!=NULL)
        {
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        temp->next=front;
        ptr->next=temp;
        rear=temp;
    }
}
    }
void dequeue()
{
    struct Node *temp=front;
    if(front!=NULL && front->next!=NULL)
    {
        rear->next=front->next;
        front=front->next;
    }
}

void display()
{
    struct Node *temp=front;
    while(temp->next!=front)
    {
        printf("%d",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("%d",rear->data);
}

void main()
{
    int n,i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter Element");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        enqueue(front,rear,n);
    }

display();

}
```

The output that I see is always `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`. I've tried running the code on multiple machines and compilers and there's no difference still.

Comment: You should include `stdlib.h` instead of `malloc.h` -- the latter is not portable.

Comment: Also, don't use `void main()`. Use `int main(void)` instead.

Comment: @JL2210 made the changes. Still didn't solve the problem

Comment: I wasn't saying they would. Your code has a lot more wrong than that. Those are just style changes.

Answer (score 0):

as a rule avoid having global variables and arguments with the same name, it is a bit confusing and maybe causing the issue you are seeing.

as your code now stands, when you change `front` inside your function you are actually not changing the global variable front, but a copy.

so either pass the address of front and rear into the function or remove the parameters completely.

```
void enqueue(struct Node **front,struct Node **rear,int ele)
{
  struct Node *temp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  struct Node* ptr=*front;
...

if (front == NULL)
{
  temp->data = ele;
  temp->next = NULL;
  *front = temp;      // this will actually change front
  printf ("%d", front->data);
}
```

and call it as

```
int n, i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  printf ("Enter Element");
  // scanf ("%d", &n); avoid using scanf like this, use instead fgets
  char line[32];
  if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL)
  { 
    int n = atoi(line); 
    enqueue (&front, &rear, n);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works without throwing segmentation fault. I've made some minor changes to the code. I guess my comments inside the code will explain the changes made to your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
}*front=NULL,*rear=NULL;

//remove the local arguments
void enqueue(int ele)
{
    struct Node *temp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* ptr=front;
    if (temp==NULL)
        printf("Overflow");
    else
    {
        if (front==NULL)
        {
            temp->data=ele;
            temp->next=NULL;
            front=temp;
            printf("%d",front->data);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Srishti");
            // check the breaking condition
            while(ptr->next!=NULL && ptr->next != front)
            {
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
            // putting the ele in the data space of Node
            temp->data = ele;
            temp->next=front;
            ptr->next=temp;
            rear=temp;
        }
    }
}

void dequeue()
{
    struct Node *temp=front;
    if(front!=NULL && front->next!=NULL)
    {
        rear->next=front->next;
        front=front->next;
    }
}

void display()
{
    struct Node *temp=front;
    while(temp->next!=front)
    {
        printf("%d",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("%d",rear->data);
}

void main()
{
    int n,i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter Element");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        enqueue(n);
    }

    display();

}
```

Answer (score -1):

First things first: always enable compiler errors and warnings. The compiler is your *friend* not your **enemy**!

From the code it is not clear what exactly you want to achieve. So for my solution I'm assuming that you want the following:

- `enqueue()` adds a new element to the end of the list
- `dequeue()` removes an element from the end of the list
- global `front` is either `NULL` (empty list) or points to the first element of the list
- global `rear` is either `NULL` (empty list) or points to the last element of the list
- when the list is empty then `front == NULL` *and* `rear == NULL`
- if the list has one entry then `front == rear`
- if the list is not empty then `rear->next == NULL`

Updated code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node* next;
} *front = NULL, *rear = NULL;

void enqueue(int ele)
{
  struct Node *temp = calloc(sizeof(struct Node), 1);

  if (temp == NULL) {
    printf("Overflow");
    exit(1);
  } else {

    if (front == NULL) {
      /* list is empty */
      front = temp;
    } else {
      /* add to end of list */
      rear->next = temp;
    }

    temp->data = ele;
    rear       = temp;
  }
}

void dequeue()
{
  /* special cases: empty or only one element */
  if (rear == front) {
    if (front != NULL)
      free(front);
    front = rear = NULL;
    return;
  }

  struct Node *temp = front;
  while (temp->next != rear)
    temp = temp->next;

  rear = temp;
  free(temp->next);
  temp->next = NULL;
}

void display()
{
  if (front == NULL)
    return;

  struct Node *temp = front;
  while (temp) {
    printf("%d\n", temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
  int n,i;

  for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
    printf("Enter Element ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    enqueue(n);
  }

  /* show list & dequeue() functionality */
  for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
    display();
    dequeue();
  }
  display();

  /* show that dequeue() is safe on empty list */
  dequeue();

  return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -o dummy dummy.c
$ valgrind ./dummy
==9093== Memcheck, a memory error detector
...
Enter Element 1
Enter Element 2
Enter Element 3
1
2
3

1
2

1

==9093== 
==9093== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9093==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9093==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 2,096 bytes allocated
==9093== 
==9093== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
...
```